# SBT fails with unresolved dependency: play-java_2.10;2.2.0 for deadbolt (Scala) 2.2-RC2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

SBT fails to resolve one of deadbolt's dependency: `play-java_2.10;2.2.0`.

Contents of `build.sbt`:

```
name := "play-deadbolt"

organization := "com.github.hanxue"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.2-RC2"
```

Contents of `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers ++= Seq(
        Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns))

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Note that I have tried adding the `resolvers` to `build.sbt` instead of `project/plugins.sbt`, with the same error.

This is what happens when I run `sbt update`

```
$ sbt update
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/hanxue/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /private/tmp/plain-deadbolt/project
[info] Set current project to play-deadbolt (in build file:/private/tmp/plain-deadbolt/)
[info] Updating {file:/private/tmp/plain-deadbolt/}plain-deadbolt...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/hanxue/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/play-java_2.10/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.10/2.2.0/play-java_2.10-2.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jan 22, 2014 12:02:53 AM
```

I have verified that the Ivy repository at http://schaloner.github.io/releases/be.objectify/deadbolt-scala_2.10/2.2-RC2/ivys/ivy.xml is valid, with the following contents:

```
<ivy-module xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra" version="2.0">
<info organisation="be.objectify" module="deadbolt-scala_2.10" revision="2.2-RC2" status="release" publication="20131027200616">
<description>deadbolt-scala</description>
</info>
<configurations>
<conf name="compile" visibility="public" description=""/>
<conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="" extends="compile"/>
<conf name="test" visibility="public" description="" extends="runtime"/>
<conf name="provided" visibility="public" description=""/>
<conf name="optional" visibility="public" description=""/>
<conf name="sources" visibility="public" description=""/>
<conf name="pom" visibility="public" description=""/>
</configurations>
<publications>
<artifact name="deadbolt-scala_2.10" type="pom" ext="pom" conf="pom"/>
<artifact name="deadbolt-scala_2.10" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="compile"/>
<artifact name="deadbolt-scala_2.10" type="src" ext="jar" conf="sources" e:classifier="sources"/>
</publications>
<dependencies>
<dependency org="org.scala-lang" name="scala-library" rev="2.10.2" conf="compile->default(compile)"/>
<dependency org="com.typesafe.play" name="play_2.10" rev="2.2.0" conf="compile->default(compile)"/>
<dependency org="com.typesafe.play" name="play-test_2.10" rev="2.2.0" conf="test->default(compile)"/>
<dependency org="com.typesafe.play" name="play-cache_2.10" rev="2.2.0" conf="compile->default(compile)"/>
<dependency org="be.objectify" name="deadbolt-core_2.10" rev="2.2-RC2" conf="compile->default(compile)"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Could this be due to play-java missing or moved at the Typesafe repository? This is a screenshot of the Typesafe repository browser at http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/webapp/browserepo.html?0&pathId=ivy-releases:com.typesafe.sbteclipse

[image: Typesafe Repository Browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `build.sbt` worked fine to resolve `"be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.2-RC2"` dependency:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.com/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

libraryDependencies += "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.2-RC2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jazek! I think this was the missing line `resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")`

Comment: I added the snippet to my multi projects (Play is not the main project) build.sbt and it failed to resolve Objectify repository. My ApplicationBuild.scala has the following line to define the lib, lazy val web = play.Project("web", path = file("web"),
    settings = standardSettings ++ Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.authorization)) dependsOn(common, gui)

where Dependencies.authorization = Seq( "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.2-RC2")